# Error when executing php file

Tags: php, windows

I am trying to execute a `.php` file in command prompt. I had installed PHP5. But when I execute im getting error:

```
Unable to find wrapper(https)
```

I googled and got to know that im missing `php_openssl.dll` file. But I have not installed xampp. Let me know if I need to install xampp to get this? or do any other set up in order to remove this error.

Comment: You should add the fact that you are aparently using MS-Windows to the question and the flags. Most people here use Linux or some other flavour of Unix instead.

Answer (score 3):

Find this line in your php.ini file:

`;extension=php_openssl.dll`

... and uncomment it (remove the preceding semicolon).

Answer (score 1):

You need to have an application like **wampserver** or **xampp** installed to run php files, then put your `.php` files in `/www/youapplicationfolder/yourphpfile` for **wampserver** or `/htdocs/youapplicationfolder/yourphpfile` for **xampp**. Then try running you file in your favorite browser and type [this is not a link]http://localhost/yourapplicationfolder/yourphpfile.php in the address bar. hth!

Comment: no other means to get that dll, configure and run? (without xampp) ??